# Why is docker-compose still using an old image when using a remote `--context`

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a node app that I am trying to deploy to my server using a remote context. However, files are not being copied to the built image on the server. I am running:

```sh
touch testing.txt                             # Make changes to the project
docker-compose --context server up --build -d # Deploy new version

docker --context server exec MY_CONTAINER pwd # /user/src/app
docker --context server exec MY_CONTAINER ls  # testing.txt not there
```

However, it updates perfectly fine when running locally

```sh
docker exec MY_CONTAINER ls # testing.txt not there

touch testing.txt
docker-compose up --build -d # Deploy new version

docker exec MY_CONTAINER ls  # testing.txt exists
```

I've even tried using force-recreate (`docker-compose --context server up --force-recreate --build -d`). The image is apparently recreated (docker ps shows a recent creation time), but the file is still not there.

The only thing that works is to delete the container and the image with `docker rm` and `docker rmi` and then rerun the first set of commands.

What's even more strange is that the `up` command after making changes says it didn't use the cached image layer:

```
# Running after a changed/added file
=> [5/6] COPY . ./
=> [6/6] RUN yarn build

# Running after nothing changed
=> CACHED [5/6] COPY . ./
=> CACHED [6/6] RUN yarn build
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Here's my files

```
### Dockerfile
FROM node:14
WORKDIR /user/src/app

COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install
COPY . ./
RUN yarn build

CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

```
### docker-compose.yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
    - "1234:4321"
    restart: always
```

```
### .dockerignore
.git
node_modules/
```

Comment: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/8837

I'm having the same issue, maybe this will help you...

Answer (score 0):

I personally solved the problem by adding an image tag

```
services:
  web:
    image: image-name:v1.0
```

Every time the name is changed, docker compose up --build recreates the image

```
Step 1) Increase the version of the tag
Step 2) Run the following commands

$ docker-compose --context CONTEXT -f docker-compose.yaml build
$ docker-compose --context CONTEXT -f docker-compose.yaml stop
$ docker-compose --context CONTEXT -f docker-compose.yaml rm -f
$ docker-compose --context CONTEXT -f docker-compose.yaml up -d --build\
```